# Why does Message Box appear twice when event is called.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events, delegates

So I've been following the Visual Studio tutorials that microsoft has available (more specifically the math quiz one found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd492172.asp)

but I deviated a bit from the tutorial because I wanted to see if I could create an event and call it using the EventHandler delegate though it might not be the best solution.

```
public event EventHAndler quizStarted;
```

here is the code for creating the event.

now in the method

```
 public Form1()
    {
        this.quizStarted += new System.EventHandler(this.showThatTheQuizStarted);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I have initialized my event with an instance of the EventHanlder that points to my showThatTheQuizStarted method.

```
public void showThatTheQuizStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Quiz Has Started");
    }
```

and finally when the start button is pressed I call the quizStarted event as shown below.

```
    private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startButton.Enabled = false;

        quizStarted(this, new EventArgs());

        this.StartTheQuiz();

    }
```

in this order the message box goes away after hitting okay once, also in StartTheQuiz() nothing calles a message box directly or indirectly.

but if I place the `this.quizStarted += new System.EventHandler(this.showThatTheQuizStarted);` line into the startButton_Click method, the message box appears twice one right after the other.

Though I found a solution I would like to know why this happens if I place this line of code out of the constructor.

Comment: You are asking the question regarding the knowingly-erroneous code snippet while you already have a correct solution. I suggest to close this question as of having no value. Thanks for the understanding. Best regards,

Comment: I assume it happens because you're attaching a new instance of the same event handler every time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

If...

```
this.quizStarted += new System.EventHandler(this.showThatTheQuizStarted);
```

... gets called multiple times, as would happen if you move it inside a button Click event handler method, then you are in fact adding and registering a new event handler every time.

In other words, when quizStarted is invoked, it may call multiple event handlers, depending on how many you choose to register.  If you register the same event handler multiple times, then it will get called as many times.

That's why you want to leave the registration in a place where you are guaranteed to register the event handler once and only once.